# How to group by values by special characters for unique ids in r

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table, tidyr

I have a data frame `df` that looks like below

```
ID  value
123 6
123 5
123 4
124 3
124 8
137 9
140 12
154 9
154 8
167 10
```

I need to group them by `comma` with respective ids and want results like below

```
ID  value
123 6,5,4
124 3,8
137 9
140 12
154 9,8
167 10
```

I have tried the below code

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% summarise(val=paste(Value, collapse=","))
```

But results like this with a single row and single column

```
val
6,5,4,3,8,9,12,9,8,10
```

kindly help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: That might be because you have `plyr` loaded. Try using `dplyr::summarise` to call the function explicitly from `dplyr`.

Comment: It works with `dplyr`